# Написать свой сервер на python(socket) или взять готовое решение(twisted)?

Tags: python, администрирование, tcp-ip

Добрых суток.

Нужно написать сервер принимающий одно-два подключения по tcp, и реализовать протокол с двунаправленной передачей данных.

Сейчас написал, на питоне, обычный многопоточный tcp-ip-сервер на библиотеке socket.

Проблема в том, что это не моя область, я в ней совсем не разбираюсь. И понятия не имею могут ли всплыть какие-то подводные камни. Может с безопасностью будут ошибки, или ещё что-то о чём я не знаю. Твистед хорош, конечно, но много зависимостей, и ненужных функций, для задачи.

Вот и думаю, достаточно ли будет самописного маленького сервера, или стоит всё-таки взять твистед, чтобы быть спокойным за вещи, о которых не вкурсе?

Comment: Twisted - это не готовый сервер, это асинхронный фреймворк. Если вы не разбираетесь в асинхронном и сетевом программировании, то шанс накосячить меньше не станет.